# Geostationary orbit

Tags: physics

We have the following governing equations for the motion of a satellite around the earth under gravity:

$\dfrac{-GM}{r^2} =\ddot{r} -r\dot{\theta}^2$

$r^2\dot{\theta} = h$

I want to find the height at which a satellite appears stationary to an observer on the surface of the earth.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Consider what the angular velocity has to be to appear stationary.  How is that related to the angular velocity of the earth?

Comment: @meawoppl I've actually looked at some solutions and they've mentioned angular velocity also, but we have yet to learn about angular velocity. Do you see any other approaches?

Comment: The question is really about relative angular velocities.    You can also think about it as the satellite needs to complete one orbit (circumfrance) per day.  Or ($2\pi \mathrm{radians}/1\mathrm{day}$)